# Chef template resource to execute if the source template changes?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I'm deploying a package that requires a template be created in a specified directory every time a directory is unzipped.

A `remote_file` notifies my unzip action, that unzip action notifies the template resource, which in turn notifies other resources. This chain of notifications works as expected.

Below is my template resource:

```
template 'C:\\Program Files\\MyProgram\\program.yml' do
  source "my_program-#{node['program']['version']}.yml.erb"
  action   :nothing
  notifies :run, 'powershell_script[install-program]', :immediately
end
```

My question: Is there a way to have the `template` resource execute if I make a change to the source template? Right now it only executes the `template` resource if notified by my unzip action (due to my `action :nothing`).

However, it would be great to have a way for it to tell if the template itself has changed. Perhaps some kind of `not_if` or `only_if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

sounds to me that you avoid all the notification chaining if you will have your resources defined in the same recipe.

back to your questions, it sounds that setting `action :create`, which is the default action, will do the trick. from the [template resource documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html#actions)

> action :create
>
> Create a file. If a file already exists (but does not match), update that file to match.